How to enable the function 'Allow multiple selections" in data validation which created by app scripts
I have a issue with my data validation; my client requests a function: fetching data from the server and filling the response into the dropdown (requiring allow multiple selections). But when I use requireValueInList to generate the dropdown, I can't find any option to enable that. (I attached 2 images below)
const rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(['Yes', 'No'], true)
  .build();
sheet.getRange(4, index + 1).setDataValidation(rule);




Looking through related articles, it seems that this is not possible as of today. Are you open to alternatives that might include html dialogs?

@4thAnd1 Thanks for your sugesstion, my client want native dropdown :'(

You might wanna take a look at this and see if this could still suit your needs

Maybe possible with Google sheets api though.

You should manually change the Display Type from Arrow to Chipset. This is because the "Allow multiple selections" is only available for this type of display.
It's worth mentioning that Using Google Apps Script, it is impossible to change the Display Type and set the option to Checked.
